# Debian Updates need to find what has installed

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have a nifty server that does our updates by a specialized script. The problem is the main admin of this is part time and rarely here.  I have Debian functioning as a device OS.  When updates get applied I need to be able to see when they got applied on the device.  I did a dpkg -l and it shows a lot besides that.  We also checked the dpkg.log in /var/log and it only shows us the date when the updates were last installed.

Comment: Might want to examine/monitor `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see when what was installed

Comment: Nothing exists in the var/log/apt directory.  How can I make sure that this gets created by my devices?

Comment: If your Debian is real pure Debian then all apt-get, etc. logs should be there.  Of course, your log rotation, etc. can all effect this...

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-cache pkgnames | tee "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_pkg.log"` provides a terser list, and you may compare it against the last time you ran it to see what's new.

Comment: Many thanks for a prompt answer.  I  do that I get the same output as sudo apt-cache pkgnames which is all the packages installed but with no dates.

Comment: Right. Run it every time there's an update. Then, you can compare it against the previous run (which is why I stuffed the ANSI formatted date into the logfile name in my example) and see what's new.